# Netbeans autocomplete not following style guide

Tags: php, netbeans

I like to have a space after function names, arrays, that sort of thing, so a function declaration would look like:

```
function myfunction ($param)
{
    $a = array ('a', 'b');
    callfunction ($a);
}
```

And although I have set the style guide in Netbeans to correspond to this whenever it does autocomplete/suggestions it always misses out the space and gives me something like `callfunction($a)` even though when I go source->format (alt+shift+f) it then formats the code properly.

Any way to get autocomplete to add the space?

**UPDATE:**

Just to make things clear, I have set up Netbeans to correspond to my coding preferences, as indicated by the ability to use auto format.  The problem is auto complete (or whatever the hint thing is called) does not respect these settings, leading to the missing space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in <kbd>Tools</kbd>-><kbd>Options</kbd>.

In pane <kbd>Editor</kbd> -> choose pane <kbd>Formatting</kbd>.

In language choose **PHP** and in **Category** choose **Spaces**.

Check all in **Before Keywords, Before Parenthesis, Before left braces**, and you can choose other properties if you want.

Then when you will use auto-complete or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to reformat it will put the spaces correctly.

EDIT :

In the OP case it seems an other configuration prevents the auto-complete to works.

This is my config :

[image]

Comment: You didn't set this as I suggest because it's totally working, when I use autocomplete I have the space between method name and "(" (i don't even have to auto format). I'm using Netbeans 7.1.1, please add your netbeans version. And be sure you done exactly what I said.

Comment: 7.1.1.  I already have set the PHP style guide and Alt+Shift+F does format the code correctly, only autocomplete doesn't format it. You've just basically explained what I already stated I do in the question.  My issue is that autocomplete not following my stated rules.

Comment: As I said in my comment it works whith autocomplete, when I typed `my` then Ctrl+Space it display `myfunction ($param)`

Comment: So if it works for me and not for you then maybe you have others options that prevent autocomplete to work. I know it's long but can you gave your Code Completion properties for PHP?

Comment: @Meep3D Also, in Editor->Code Completion-> All Languages. Have you checked the option `Insert Closing Brackets Auto`? It doesn't work without this option.

Comment: It's checked.  What about system function such as trigger_error, are they working too?

Comment: Yes it prints `trigger_error ($error_msg)`, I'll edit my answer with a screenshot of the Code Completion config for PHP. Tell me if you have the same. If it still doesn't work I fear it's a bug in Netbeans, and you'll have to reinstall it to make it works (it will not be the first time reinstallation is needed in Netbeans...)

Comment: A re-install seemed to help a little bit, but not much - sometimes it's ok, sometimes it isn't.  Guess it's just Netbeans being Netbeans.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm sorry you still have this strange behaviour sometimes, I hope the next version will be less buggy!

Answer (score 2):

Do this:
Goto Options > Formatting

Scroll down to "Spaces Before Parenthesis"

Check the option called  "Function Declaration"